# What's the correct and optimized way to make huge arrays?

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine

I am making a game which is going to be based around questions that player has to answer. I want the player to be able to purchase question packs. Question packs are arrays, which look something like this:

```
public string[] questionPack1 = new string[5] { "Question1?", "Question2?", "Question3?", "Question4?", "Question5?" };
```

Right now there is 5 questions, but in my game one question pack is going to consist 25x questions each, and there will be 10+ question packs.

**My question is** whats the best place to write those question packs? In a different script and then access them somehow?

Comment: In my opinion this kind of things rather belongs into a proper JSON format and then it is up to you whether you have them all in a single file and load them all into memory and then pick questions or whether you rather only store a directory link, pick one file and load its content .... Anyway: 25 * 10 => 250 strings ... that's by far not a "huge array" ;)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, managed to set it up!

Comment: An array of 250 strings is nothing, don't be concerned. If your array is like > 100,000 long strings come back and ask.

Comment: Referring to the part of your question asking for the "best place" to write down this strings, I would like to mention [scriptable objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html), which can be really useful for such things. Anyway, I think you should not save this strings in your actual source code, but in (a) separate file(s) of some form.